# display name causes invalid email error when using GmailApp.SendMail

Tags: javascript, email

I am using GmailApp to forward messages from our community from one member to others who have said they want to receive these notices.  I extract their first name (which can include middle name or initial), last name, and email address from a Google spreadsheet. The information is then formatted as first name, space, last name, space, LT symbol, email address, GT symbol, a comma, space, and then the next address.

I have always thought that the display name was whatever I wanted it to be, but it appears that the GmailApp is testing to see if the display name is equal to the name on the Gmail account.  Is this so?  Is there any way to overcome this condition if it is true?

Here is what happens:
If my Gmail name is Dale Smythe and my Gmail address is dsxx16@gmail.com, I structure the address as - Dale Smythe <"dsxx16@gmail.com"> and the message is successfully sent. On the other hand, if I structure the address as - Dale K. Smythe <"dsxx16@gmail.com"> I get a script error message of "invalid email".  Please disregard the quotes inside of the brackets, as this was the only way I could find to get the email address portion to display on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

After additional testing, I have determined that the invalid email message is the result of the period in the display name (e.g., after an initial).  If the period is removed, the error message is not issued and the email is sent.